# Separating date and time from timestamp

Tags: r, datetime

I have looked at different options from previous answers, but none has given me the correct output.
I would like to separate `timestamp` into `date` and `time` using R

```
sorted_transactions_table$TRANSACTION_DATE <- as.Date(sorted_transactions_table$TRANSACTION_TIME)
```

I  have tried this but I get an error:

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

Timestamp from my dataset is in the format:

**01-OCT-18 12.01.23.000000 AM**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it into standard datetime format first and then use `format`

```
df$TRANSACTION_DATE <- as.POSIXct(df$TRANSACTION_DATE, 
                      format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%OS %p")
transform(df, Date = as.Date(TRANSACTION_DATE), 
              #Also Date = format(TRANSACTION_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") would work
              time = format(TRANSACTION_DATE, "%T"))

#  col1    TRANSACTION_DATE       Date     time
#1    1 2018-10-01 12:01:23 2018-10-01 12:01:23
#2    2 2018-10-01 12:02:23 2018-10-01 12:02:23
#3    3 2018-10-01 12:03:23 2018-10-01 12:03:23
```

You could also do this in `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(TRANSACTION_DATE = as.POSIXct(TRANSACTION_DATE, 
                           format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%OS %p"), 
     Date = as.Date(TRANSACTION_DATE), 
     time = format(TRANSACTION_DATE, "%T"))
```

Read `?strptime` for all formatting options.

**data**

Using a reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, TRANSACTION_DATE = c("01-OCT-18 12.01.23.000000 AM", 
                 "01-OCT-18 12.02.23.000000 AM", "01-OCT-18 12.03.23.000000 AM"))

df
#  col1             TRANSACTION_DATE
#1    1 01-OCT-18 12.01.23.000000 AM
#2    2 01-OCT-18 12.02.23.000000 AM
#3    3 01-OCT-18 12.03.23.000000 AM
```

Comment: If you're trying this and like for me, it's not working, check your `Sys.getlocale()`. The OCT was not recognized as for my machine it should be OKT. You can change your locale with for instance `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")` (for Windows)

Comment: Yes, this is well outlined and explained. It works too. Thank You @RonakShah

Comment: @Sven Well noted, it works with me since English is my default. But thank you for your addition, it might help someone out there

Answer (score 2):

I would use the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(TRANSACTION_DATE = dmy_hms(TRANSACTION_DATE),
         Date = date(TRANSACTION_DATE), 
         time = format(TRANSACTION_DATE, "%T"))
```